# heap corruption not detected by appverify

Tags: c, windows, heap-corruption

I have created a program that responds on windows filesystem api calls (winfsp)
it first allocate memory needed by all threads (based on tunable options)
and forks to a background process
It works, but after a while it crashes due to HEAP corruptions
if I use appverify or gflags to detect corruptions, than the program stops immediately as appverify or gflags thinks there is a memory leakage in the father process?

any suggestions how to get appverify or gflags to detect the actual heap corruptions?
continuing on child process and all threads

Comment: Windows doesn't use the `fork` model. Memory allocated in the parent process does not get inherited by children.

Comment: its started as a service, SvcStart, SvcStop. If I use appverify, than the program doesn’t run at all after the SvcStart call